# How to uninstall ubuntu studio low latency kernel

Tags: kernel, ubuntu-studio

I recently installed the ubuntu studio software alongside its low latency kernel on my vanilla ubuntu installation. I checked "allow OS to boot low latency kernel as default" and (since im dualbooting with windows), it instead just added a low latency ubuntu option in my grub bootlauncher. I want to now get rid of this kernal and, (since im a noob and have no idea) get rid of the option to launch it grub launcher and , by to not launch it default (As i plan to get rid of windows and just use ubuntu as my OS).